# Conecting client and server via TCP on to separate machines

Tags: java, linux, windows, sockets, tcp

I have a code that works fine when I try to connect a client and a server on localhost using TCP sockets. Here is my code:

**Server**

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket (PORT);
serverSocket.setSoTimeout(TIMEOUT);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream (clientSocket.getOutputStream());
//...
// out.writeObject(...);
// close the sockets and the output stream
```

**Client**

```
Socket socket = new Socket (SERVER_NAME, PORT);
socket.setSoTimeout (TIMEOUT);
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream (socket.getInputStream());
//...
//... = in.readObject();
// close the socket and the input stream
```

As you can see is a very simple code that should work with no problems. As a matter of fact, it does work until `SERVER_NAME` is something diferent that `"localhost"`.

I am making my tests using the vitualizacion software VMWare. My operating system is Windows and the operating system of the virtual machine is the Linux distribution CentOS.

Where should I get `SERVER_NAME`?

**Edit**: Once I get right `SERVER_NAME` I get the following exception on the client (executing on the virtual machine):

```
java.net.ConnectException: Conexión rehusada (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at Cliente.<init>(Cliente.java:64)
    at Cliente.main(Cliente.java:28)
```

Do I have to configure the firewall or some security option?

Comment: Try using IP address to set your `SERVER_NAME`. You can examine it with `ip a` on linux or `ipconfig/all` on wiindows.

Comment: Windows: `ipconfig /all`   Linux: `ip route list` (check src column)

Comment: Thank you both for your help I have solved part of the problem

Comment: Have you checked the firewall of the system running the server? By default most systems block all ports/applications.

Comment: How do I check that on Windows? @Robert

Comment: @jpuriol Enter "firewall" in the start menu search field, open the firewall configurator and search for the entries of java.